# Android forgot alias password

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, alias

I have an app and I need to update, I have the .keystore and the passowrd, but I don't remember my Key alias password, How I can recovery it? Can I create new alias? And update the app in google play.

Answer (score 1):

there is no way to recover that password so you have to make a new keystore without wasting your time but remember then after that you have to change your package name to upload app on play store..